# Gradle FileTree directories only

Tags: file, gradle, groovy, directory

Given a directory `dir`:

```
dir
├── sub1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── sub2
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── sub3
    ├── file1
    └── file2
```

`fileTree('dir').each { println it }` gives me this:

```
dir/sub1/file1
dir/sub1/file2
dir/sub2/file1
dir/sub2/file2
dir/sub3/file1
dir/sub3/file2
```

Instead of all the file, I just want all the directories and subdirectories:

```
dir/
dir/sub1/
dir/sub2/
dir/sub3/
```

How do I do that? I've looked at `DirectoryTree`, but it does not extend `FileCollection` (unlike `FileTree`), so it's not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

What about this :

```
file('dir').eachFileRecurse(FileType.DIRECTORIES) { println it }
```

Gives :

```
dir/sub1/
dir/sub2/
dir/sub3/
```

Comment: This a Groovy extension method on File, therefore it's eager, not calculated at the time of task execution, but at configuration time. This is generally discouraged for a multitude of reasons. Sadly there's [no good API for it](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14152).

Answer (score 0):

`FileTree.getFiles()` returns only the files in the tree, not the directories.

I needed to do the following to get the directories

```
List<File> dirs = []
fileTree(dir).visit { FileVisitDetails fvd ->
   if (fvd.directory) {
      dirs << fvd.file
   }
}
doStuff(dirs)
```